# Non-Constant Generator Single-Pass Initialization during Construction

Tags: c++, initialization, stdvector, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-access

Is there a way to construct a new `std::vector` with *uninitialized* (non-zero) values or even prettier through a *generator* (similar to [`std::generate_n()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/generate_n/)) constructor argument that produces the desired *non-standard* (non-constant) values *without* first initializing all elements to zero? This because I want a (random) mockup-creation api to be as locality-efficient as possible, thereby only writing container elements once. Wouldn't it be neat to have a generator-constructor for the `std::vector` (and possibly others)?! Why hasn't C++ already added this to the Standard?

The following constructor-like C function illustrates the write-once-behaviour I seek for the custom-initialize construction of `std::vector`:

```
// Allocate-and-Generate a random int array of length \p n.
int * gen_rand(size_t n)
{
  int *v = malloc(n); // allocate only 
  for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++) {
    v[i] = rand(); // first write
  }
}
```

I believe it boils down to the behaviour of the STL Allocator used, since it is responsible for writing the initial zeros (or not).

If we use the `std::vector` constructor with iterators we first have to allocate and write the random values somewhere else, even worse than using `push_back()`.

Comment: Iterators are how you do this. Look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html

Comment: @EthanSteinberg: An iterator solution for std::vector either require using `push_back()` which is less efficient or again result in writing to elements twice. For others, such as `std::list`, iterators may be a good solution.

Comment: You can use iterators in a constructor ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can precede the use of the generator with a call to `vector::reserve`. This will have exactly the same behavior as the C code you show. You will still need to use a `back_insert_iterator` as the size of the `vector` will still be zero.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v;
  v.reserve(10);
  std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), 10, []() { return rand(); });
  for(auto x : v)
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
  // unsafe version
  std::vector<int> v2;
  // 10 uninitialized integers
  v2.resize(10);
  // make sure never to write more than the exact amount, otherwise this will be UB
  std::generate_n(v.begin(), 10, []() { return rand(); });

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe some extra conditional statements regarding vector size checking will be added during iteration in the C++ version, but no reallocations. Close enough.

Comment: @Nordlöw The size of the vector will only be checked for the push_back operation. `resize` will only check the `capacity`. I've added a version that avoids that, although I consider it unsafe.